# combining two tables query

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

i came across the following problem

i would like to sum someone absence using mysql with across within these twop codes

```
SELECT  a.nama_account,
             a.jabatan,
             b.nama_tp,
             a.jam_berangkat,
             a.jam_pulang,
             (SUM(IF((jam_awal < jam_berangkat) AND (jam_akhir > jam_pulang),'1','0'))+dinas+dinastp) jum,
             DATEDIFF('$tgl2','$tgl1')+1 jumhar
            FROM t_account a
            LEFT JOIN t_tp b ON a.tp_ID=b.ID
            LEFT JOIN t_user c ON a.userCode=c.userCode
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT  DATE(`tanggal`) tgl,
                            phoneNumber,
                            MIN(TIME( tanggal)) jam_awal,
                            MAX(TIME( tanggal)) jam_akhir,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '1234','1','0')) dinas,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '4321','1','0')) dinastp
                        FROM    t_report 
                        WHERE ( tanggal BETWEEN '$tgl1 00:00:00' AND '$tgl2 23:59:59' )
                        GROUP BY DATE(tanggal),phoneNumber
                     ) tlis
                 ON tlis.phoneNumber = a.`imei_number`
            WHERE a.grup_ID = '$grup'
            $queryIf
            AND (c.user_status !='3' AND c.user_status != '999') 
            GROUP BY a.`imei_number`
            ORDER BY b.nama_tp,a.jabatan
```

AND

```
SELECT  a.nama_account,
             a.jabatan,
             b.nama_tp,
             a.jam_berangkat,
             a.jam_pulang,
             (SUM(IF((jam_awal < jam_berangkat) AND (jam_akhir > '$jampulang_sabtu'),'1','0'))+dinas+dinastp) jum,
             DATEDIFF('$tgl2','$tgl1')+1 jumhar
            FROM t_account a
            LEFT JOIN t_tp b ON a.tp_ID=b.ID
            LEFT JOIN t_user c ON a.userCode=c.userCode
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT  DATE(`tanggal`) tgl,
                            phoneNumber,
                            MIN(TIME( tanggal)) jam_awal,
                            MAX(TIME( tanggal)) jam_akhir,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '1234','1','0')) dinas,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '4321','1','0')) dinastp
                        FROM    t_report 
                        WHERE ( tanggal BETWEEN '$tgl1 00:00:00' AND '$tgl2 23:59:59') AND DAYNAME(tanggal)='Saturday'
                        GROUP BY DATE(tanggal),phoneNumber
                     ) tlis
                 ON tlis.phoneNumber = a.`imei_number`
            WHERE a.grup_ID = '$grup'
            $queryIf
            AND (c.user_status !='3' AND c.user_status != '999') 
            GROUP BY a.`imei_number`
            ORDER BY b.nama_tp,a.jabatan
```

i wanna get the combine number of jum in each query, is there anything i can do with 1 query instead having these two? because its a trouble to loopin it on php echo.

thanks

Comment: What are you getting now as opposed to desired results? You didn't say. I can't see where you're querying/echoing neither. What is the sample data?

Comment: from the two codes, i get the data i want. for weekdays and 'special hour' saturday. but im troubling in combining these two into 1 query, or fit in it in my php. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Please use standard grammar & punctuation. Also this is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Show what you have tried & where you are stuck. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StevenC. it sounds like you need to use a `UNION` to put the results of the 2 queries together.

Here's how you would do it:

```
SELECT nama_account,
    jabatan,
    nama_tp,
    jam_berangkat,
    jam_pulang,
    jumhar,
    SUM(jum) AS jumTotal
FROM (
SELECT  a.nama_account,
             a.jabatan,
             b.nama_tp,
             a.jam_berangkat,
             a.jam_pulang,
             (SUM(IF((jam_awal < jam_berangkat) AND (jam_akhir > jam_pulang),'1','0'))+dinas+dinastp) jum,
             DATEDIFF('$tgl2','$tgl1')+1 jumhar
            FROM t_account a
            LEFT JOIN t_tp b ON a.tp_ID=b.ID
            LEFT JOIN t_user c ON a.userCode=c.userCode
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT  DATE(`tanggal`) tgl,
                            phoneNumber,
                            MIN(TIME( tanggal)) jam_awal,
                            MAX(TIME( tanggal)) jam_akhir,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '1234','1','0')) dinas,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '4321','1','0')) dinastp
                        FROM    t_report 
                        WHERE ( tanggal BETWEEN '$tgl1 00:00:00' AND '$tgl2 23:59:59' )
                        GROUP BY DATE(tanggal),phoneNumber
                     ) tlis
                 ON tlis.phoneNumber = a.`imei_number`
            WHERE a.grup_ID = '$grup'
            $queryIf
            AND (c.user_status !='3' AND c.user_status != '999') 
            GROUP BY a.`imei_number`
            ORDER BY b.nama_tp,a.jabatan

UNION

SELECT  a.nama_account,
             a.jabatan,
             b.nama_tp,
             a.jam_berangkat,
             a.jam_pulang,
             (SUM(IF((jam_awal < jam_berangkat) AND (jam_akhir > '$jampulang_sabtu'),'1','0'))+dinas+dinastp) jum,
             DATEDIFF('$tgl2','$tgl1')+1 jumhar
            FROM t_account a
            LEFT JOIN t_tp b ON a.tp_ID=b.ID
            LEFT JOIN t_user c ON a.userCode=c.userCode
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT  DATE(`tanggal`) tgl,
                            phoneNumber,
                            MIN(TIME( tanggal)) jam_awal,
                            MAX(TIME( tanggal)) jam_akhir,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '1234','1','0')) dinas,
                            SUM(IF(saran = '4321','1','0')) dinastp
                        FROM    t_report 
                        WHERE ( tanggal BETWEEN '$tgl1 00:00:00' AND '$tgl2 23:59:59') AND DAYNAME(tanggal)='Saturday'
                        GROUP BY DATE(tanggal),phoneNumber
                     ) tlis
                 ON tlis.phoneNumber = a.`imei_number`
            WHERE a.grup_ID = '$grup'
            $queryIf
            AND (c.user_status !='3' AND c.user_status != '999') 
            GROUP BY a.`imei_number`
            ORDER BY b.nama_tp,a.jabatan
) AS derivedTable
GROUP BY nama_account,
    jabatan,
    nama_tp,
    jam_berangkat,
    jam_pulang,
    jumhar;
```

There you go: the combined total of the values of `jum` from the 2 queries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @StevenC. just realized I accidentally left out the column `nama_tp` in my answer. just updated it so `nama_tp` is included now. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: its okay mate, i knew. but thanks for providing the UNION things. 
and for need editing, you need to brackets each query before u UNION it.